# OpenVPN, install a TAP adapter

Tags: windows-7, vpn, network-adapter, openvpn

When I try to connect to my work VPN using OpenVPN, the connection fails with the message:

```
All TAP-Win32 adapters on this system are currently in use.
```

Many sources suggest to look in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections an enable the TAP adapter, but when I look there, there is none. Now I've run `addtap.bat` which is provided with OpenVPN, but I still don't get to see any TAP adapter, and logging in in VPN still fails. The output of addtap.bat is

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin\tapinstall.exe" install
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\driver\OemWin2k.inf" tap0801
Device node created. Install is complete when drivers are updated...
Updating drivers for tap0801 from C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\driver\OemWin2k
.inf.
Drivers updated successfully.
```

I've Run As Administrator both the setup of OpenVPN and `addtap.bat`. 
I've run `deltapall.bat` to remove any (maybe hidden) adapters. It said it removed three of them, after which I ran `addtap.bat` again to try to create another one.
I also run OpenVPN itself as administrator. What's wrong?

Running Windows 7 Home Premium on a HP Pavilion dv7 4050ed. It has worked before, but I recently had to reinstall my laptop, for which I used the restore disks I created when I just got it. Everything else seems to work fine.

== UPDATE ==

The TAP adapter is found in Device Manager, but apparently it is disabled because it is incompatible with Windows 7 64bit. I've deïnstalled OpenVPNGui, downloaded a version that should be 64bit compatible, and installed that. Still no cigar. 
Then I found a tip to install OpenVPN (version 9) after installing OpenVPNGui, because that installs OpenVPN version 8. Now I got a v9 TAP driver in Device Manager, but it still doesn't work and shows up in device manager with an exclamation mark, and not at all in my network devices.

Comment: Apparently, TAP-adapter is not a tag?

Comment: Not an answer to this issue perhaps, but on Windows 7 with OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-w64-mingw32, running that addtap.bat script resulted in adapters that didn't connect properly, for me. After troubleshooting for a while, I tried manually executing the "devcon" command from the script, but specifying the OemVista.inf instead of the OemWin2k.inf file, and the resulting adapter worked immediately.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same problem.  What worked for me is to install the latest version of the OpenVPN GUI (openvpn-2.0.9-gui-1.0.3-install), reboot, stop OpenVPN, then install the latest version of just OpenVPN (openvpn-2.1.3-install) over the top of the original install.  Make sure to do these installs with administrative rights.

The method is documented here: https://yeri.be/openvpn-windows-7

Comment: Thanks for your response. I managed to get it working before your answer by installing an older version, but I forgot to check back on the question. Anyway, I'm afraid to try your solution, since I've got it working now and I don't want to break it again.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about this question, but I actually managed to get it working shortly after I posted it. I've installed OpenVPN various times and always with administrator rights, but it wouldn't work.

After a day of messing around I gave up, but tried again a couple of days later. That time I found a source stating that the latest OpenVPN could give trouble, so I installed an earlier version (still in the 2. range). That apparently did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I make it work after I downloaded and installed tap-windows-9.21.1.exe.
After then OpenVPN GUI bring up the TAP virtual adapter and established connection.